# insert in list of python

Tags: list, insert

I want insert list in list_of_words includes some value such that any list placed in position -2 of the list_of_words but the data are not ordered as I want

```
def h(i):
a, b = i.split(';')
list_of_words = [['z', -1],['z', len(b)]]
for key, word in enumerate(a):
    if b.find(word) != -1:
        list_of_words.insert(-2, [word, b.find(word)])
print list_of_words

h("XMJYAUZ;MZJAWXU")
```

list

```
list_of_words = [['z', -1], ['z', 7]]
```

assumed after run code

```
list_of_words = [['z', -1], ['X', 5], ['M', 0], ['J', 2], ['A', 3], ['U', 6], ['Z', 1], ['z', 7]]
```

but

```
list_of_words = [['X', 5], ['M', 0], ['J', 2], ['A', 3], ['U', 6], ['Z', 1], ['z', -1], ['z', 7]]
```

why this is happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to place an item to the -2 position in a list, you will need to use

```py
list_of_words.insert(-1, [word, b.find(word)])
```

instead of

```py
list_of_words.insert(-2, [word, b.find(word)])
```

because the item will be inserted *before* the provided position rather than after.

Full code:

```py
def h(i):
    a, b = i.split(';')
    list_of_words = [['z', -1], ['z', len(b)]]
    for word in a:
        if word in b:
            list_of_words.insert(-1, [word, b.find(word)])
    print list_of_words

h("XMJYAUZ;MZJAWXU")
```